# How to access an ImageView in my Custom TableviewCell without making its outlet

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, tableview, uitableview

I have an ImageView in my TableView Cell xib, I want to access this image view in my viewController but i don't want to make an outlet of imageView i.e. in my cell as i can access my Cell in ViewController ,so how can i make access to the image view.
Thanks in advance

Comment: but i don't want to make an outlet of imageView. if you don't want outlet then you can set frame of imageview in cell class.write some code what you want actually.

Comment: whats your reasoning for not making in an outlet? Seems like that makes it incredibly simple and requires minimal effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're wanting to find the imageView in your code's `cellForRowAt` function, so that you can set its image.

In the design of the cell, give the UIImageView a tag (eg. 7). Then within your code after you have retrieved the cell, you can find the imageView using:

```
let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(7) as! UIImageView
```